# there was an error starting the websockets transport android

Tags: android, websocket, asp.net-core-mvc, signalr, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to implement a chat application using asp.net core signalr from android mobile to web and was referring the link https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-samples/tree/master/AndroidJavaClient to implement the same. The chat is working fine for web to web but while trying to connect from mobile getting the below error.

## there was an error starting the websockets transport

Already spent a day on tracing the issue.

Can somebody helps me in resolving this.

Comment: Finally found the solution. Have enabled Websocket option in azure and it got worked...

Answer (score 0):

Enabled the web sockets in azure to resolve the issue.

[image]